# Tunneling specific webserver port on localhost using SSH

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, access-control-list, ssh-tunnel

It is possible allow website surfing running on a specific port (10000) only accessing it trough SSH tunnel?

Real case:

- Apache is running on port 80 for http and 443 for https, anyone can surf all contents in all virtual host using those ports.
- Webmin is running on port 10000 but only from my client machines is possible to access it using browser in SSH tunnel, so only administrator can see that website.

Unfortunately i cannot use OpenVPN and my internet connection doesn't have static IP address.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want Webmin to bind to more interfaces than just loopback? That can probably be configured. If not: stunnel can forward connections from external interfaces to loopback. Using some strange kernel features it shall even be possible to forward from eth to lo. What relation does your dynamic IP have to the problem? That doesn't make a difference between SSH and OpenVPN.

Comment: i want webmin bind to localhost and i want access it using my browser trough SSH Tunnel. using `http://website.com:10000` must be not possible get webmin login page.
About openVPN and static IP i mean (maybe too much implicit sorry) i already thought and tried those solutions but is not possible use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tought was so hard...
just looked a couple of man pages.

On server i bound webmin to listen connections only on localhost and on my client i did:

```
ssh user@host -L 10000:127.0.0.1:10000 -N
```

Now i can manage Webmin using a (quite) secure channel.

Thanks anyway!